# Trouble with updating CSS on website

Tags: css, caching, refresh

When you guys look at this website: http://www.canadianoutback.com/events/crime_investigators.php

If you look at the links on the left nav under Explore Events, is the hover colour red #FF0000 or navy?

I'm going crazy because I can't seem to update the CSS on this website, and then I tested with changing the hover colour to #FF0000 and now it's stuck like that and I can't seem to make any further changes. I have tried deleting the CSS file, renaming it, deleting the cache, trying different browsers, different devices, but I can't seem to change the hover from #FF0000 to its original colour (or any other CSS for that matter).

The CSS file specifically should be screen.css.

Here is the code:

```
#rightColumn a:hover, #leftNav a:hover {
color: #104b7d;
text-decoration: none;}
```

Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

Using the Google Chrome Inspector:

The hover color #rightColumn a:hover, #leftNav a:hover is color: #104b7d so it's navy

The visited and normal state color is color: #910d07;

So if you were trying to change it to navy, it worked. If you didn't see the updates, it most likely a caching issue. try viewing using an incognito/private tab to see the changes.

Answer (score 1):

Could please try this code  `#leftNav .levelOne .trigger a:hover, #leftNav .levelOne .trigger a:focus { color: #FF0000; }` it not working make it `{ color: #FF0000 !important; }`